# Sorting alphabetically first, then numerically on a concatenated key

Tags: perl, sorting

Given an array of Letter_Number combinations, how can I sort by letter first, then number:

```
( B_5   A_11   C_0   A_10    A_1 )
```

to get:

```
( A_1   A_10   A_11   B_5    C_0 )
```

?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

By default, sort compares lexically. So if you want to treat the numbers as actual numbers where 010 > 1 and 2 < 11, then this is more like what you need:

```
my @list = qw(B_5 A_11 C_0 A_10 A_1);
my @sorted = sort char_then_num @list;

sub char_then_num {
    my ($a_char, $a_num) = split '_', $a;
    my ($b_char, $b_num) = split '_', $b;
    return $a_char cmp $b_char
             ||
        $a_num <=> $b_num;
}
```

Comment: The disadvantage of this method is that it splits certain elements repeatedly, and more importantly, it has duplicate code.

Comment: @ikegami I think this is easier to read for people newer to perl, including me.

Comment: @ikegami I ran the sort both ways, using maps and using splits, using his 5 elements. Using the splits was faster by more than an order of magnitude.

Comment: @ikegami make sure I'm not missing something comparing the two : https://gist.github.com/anonymous/68a59f2d8027273c70ab

Comment: @kjprice: Yes, easier to read, and my array will never contain more than 96 elements so speed isn't an issue here.

Comment: @kjprice: With bigger array there will be bigger difference.

Comment: @kjprice, https://gist.github.com/anonymous/5978996 Yours is actually a itsy fraction faster (not an order of magnitude, 10.0 microsecond vs 10.8 microsecond), even for somewhat longer lists. The overhead of ST is not making up the savings.

Comment: @ikegami, Can you tell me why my calculation is off?

Comment: @ikegami: Making proper [benchmark](http://stackoverflow.com/a/17601923/49197) seems harder than one expected. Many same values makes much less comparisons in sort than random ones.

Comment: @Hynek -Pichi- Vychodil, I did realise that using the same value for the longer list could affect the result, but there's no telling what the OP's data set is.

Answer (score 4):

```
use Sort::Key::Natural qw( natsort );
my @sorted = natsort @data;
```

Or if you wanted to avoid modules,

```
my @sorted =
   map $_->[0],
    sort {  $a->[1] cmp $b->[1] || $a->[2] <=> $b->[2] }
     map [ $_, split /_/ ],
      @data;
```

Comment: Is the second one Schwartzian transform?

Comment: Yes. It inflates each item with the split data, sorts on it, then deflates back to the original item.

Answer (score 1):

Try the CPAN module Sort::Naturally.

Answer (score 1):

Easy and efficient:

```
my @list = qw(B_5 A_11 C_0 A_10 A_2);

my @sorted = map $_->[0], sort {$a->[1] cmp $b->[1] or $a->[2] <=> $b->[2]} map [$_, split'_'], @list;
```

**Edit**:

Using Schwartzian Transformation makes huge difference even for pretty small values:

```
#!/usr/bin/perl

use Benchmark qw( cmpthese );

our $chars = join("","A".."Z");

sub genlist
{
    my $count = shift;
    return map join("_", substr($chars, rand(26),1), int(rand(100))),
        1 .. $count;
}

sub nostcmp {
    my ($a_char, $a_num) = split '_', $a;
    my ($b_char, $b_num) = split '_', $b;
    return $a_char cmp $b_char
             ||
        $a_num <=> $b_num;
}

sub nost {
   return sort nostcmp @_;
}

sub st {
    return
       map $_->[0],
        sort { $a->[1] cmp $b->[1] || $a->[2] <=> $b->[2] }
         map [ $_, split '_' ],
          @_;
}


my %tests = (
   nost => 'my @sorted = nost(@list);',
   st   => 'my @sorted = st(@list);',
);


$_ = 'use strict; use warnings; our @list; ' . $_
   for values %tests;

sub measure
{
    my $count = shift;
    print "Count $count:\n";
    local our @list = genlist($count);
    cmpthese(-3, \%tests);
    print "\n";
}

measure $_ for 5,10,20,50,100;
```

And results:

```
Count 5:
         Rate nost   st
nost  82195/s   -- -21%
st   103392/s  26%   --

Count 10:
        Rate nost   st
nost 35430/s   -- -34%
st   53589/s  51%   --

Count 20:
        Rate nost   st
nost 13228/s   -- -48%
st   25277/s  91%   --

Count 50:
       Rate nost   st
nost 4157/s   -- -53%
st   8935/s 115%   --

Count 100:
       Rate nost   st
nost 1637/s   -- -58%
st   3889/s 138%   --
```

Comment: You was faster ;-) We both know why and how use Schwartzian transformation.

Answer (score -2):

The order you're looking for is already sort's default behavior... so just sort:

```
my @list = qw(B_5 A_11 C_0 A_10 A_1);
my @sorted = sort @list;
```

Comment: Probably the original poster does not like the result if "A_2" is added.

Comment: default sort is lexicographic, not numeric

Comment: No, it's not. He just used wrong example. Here is counter example `qw(B_5 A_11 C_0 A_10 A_5)`. `A_5` should be first.

Comment: I think your downvotes are rather premature -- OP did not specify he was looking for natural sort of the numeric part.

Comment: He said he wanted to sort the numbers. You code places 10 before 5.

Comment: I'm well aware of what code does. My point is that "sort the numbers" doesn't automatically and only mean "perform a natural numeric sort in ascending order." He could very well want it in lexical order -- the OP's intention in that regard was unclear.